# How to combine vertical and horizontal lineargradientbrush in Image.OpacityMask

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have Image.
I want make blur edge for Image.
I can add on Image.OpacityMask only one LinearGradientBrush and make only Horizontal or only Vertical blurred edge:

```
<Image Height="300" Width="450" Name="oldImg" Source="/untitled.jpg">
 <Image.OpacityMask>
  <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
   <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="Transparent"></GradientStop>
   <GradientStop Offset=".3" Color="Black"></GradientStop>
   <GradientStop Offset=".7" Color="Black"></GradientStop>
   <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="Transparent"></GradientStop>
  </LinearGradientBrush>
 </Image.OpacityMask>
</Image>
```

How to combine vertical and horizontal lineargradientbrush?

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to stack two rectangles on top of the image ...

```
<Grid>
<Image Height="300" Width="450" Name="oldImg" Source="/untitled.jpg"></Image>
 <Rectangle >
  <Rectangle.Fill>
    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
     <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="White"></GradientStop>
     <GradientStop Offset=".3" Color="Transparent"></GradientStop>
     <GradientStop Offset=".7" Color="Transparent"></GradientStop>
     <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="White"></GradientStop>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
  </Rectangle.Fill>
  </Rectangle>
 <Rectangle>
  <Rectangle.Fill>
    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
     <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="White"></GradientStop>
     <GradientStop Offset=".3" Color="Transparent"></GradientStop>
     <GradientStop Offset=".7" Color="Transparent"></GradientStop>
     <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="White"></GradientStop>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
  </Rectangle.Fill>
  </Rectangle>
</Grid>
```

I don't think you can apply multiple brushes within a fill / mask.

Comment: thanks. But I suggest that it doesn't resolve my problem. May be using LinearGradientBrush is bad solution and you can offer other solution?

Comment: My problem is wider, because I have two Image controls (it look like as layers). And I want blur edges on top image, that I can see second image (where edges is blured)